# Getting java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LINUX in Callable thread?

Tags: java, firefox, exception, selenium, callable

I am running Selenium test cases by using Callable threads and I am getting **java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LINUX** exception at **executerService.submit(callable).get()** this line when I tried to run test case.

My test cases are Callable and for every test case I create callable object and submit it, but after submit I am getting

```
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LINUX
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
        at com.xyz.TestManager.startTest(TestManager.java:142)
        at com.ensarm.crawler.socket.SocketServerThread.run(SocketServerThread.java:57)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LINUX
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.isOnLinux(FirefoxBinary.java:60)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.startProfile(FirefoxBinary.java:72)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.clean(FirefoxBinary.java:225)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:80)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:215)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:106)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:154)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:150)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:97)
        at com.ensarm.crawler.web.browser.FirefoxBrowser.initialize(FirefoxBrowser.java:308)

at com.xyz.navigator.IpProxyNavigator.initialize(IpProxyNavigator.java:46)
        at com.xyz.tests.TestThread.call(TestThread.java:56)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
```

I am using following jars:
**selenium-firefox-driver-2.20.0.jar, webdriver-common-0.9.7376.jar, webdriver-firefox-0.9.7376.jar** and my fireFox version is **3.6.23**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root Cause**
The referred [Platform.LINUX](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Platform.html) field in the source is absent.

**Fix**
You need to upgrade to the latest version of selenium jar.